# A library like google maps but not really

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm searching for a library to do something like google maps but not with maps:

I have an imageView in which I want to zoom in/out. On this imageView, there are some pins (placed with an x and an y) that I can click to open a little view with a title and a button... juste like when you clic somewhere with google maps.

Does this exists? Or is it possible to do that with the google maps api?

Answer (score 0):

you can try using openstreetmaps with a custom image. you can add markers like with google maps.

http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/